# Plot geom_segment on geom_rect background

Tags: r, ggplot2, background, rect, segment

I want to plot line segments (to be precise: `geom_segment` element) on a `geom_rect` with a dark green fill.

I use the following code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=X0, y=Y0, xend=X1, yend=Y1))+
  geom_segment(aes(colour=Result)) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("green", "red"))+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_line( colour = "white") )+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(20,100, by=5))+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 0, xmax = 100, ymin = 62, ymax = 100), 
            fill = "grey") +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 0, xmax = 100, ymin = 60, ymax = 62), 
            fill = "darkgreen")+ 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 0 , xmax = 100, ymin = 50, ymax = 60), 
            fill = "darkgreen", colour = "white", size = 1)+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 50, xmax = 50, ymin = 60, ymax = 65), 
            fill = "yellow", colour = "yellow", size = 4)
```

... so on.

This gives me:

[image]

Comment: What result did you expect?

Comment: I expected the line segments (geom_segment) to be plotted on top of the geom_rect but clearly it is underneath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the order listed is the order drawn so putting geom_segment last should do it.

Comment: great! best to accept answer so others know quickly.